# EditorExit event handler called recursively

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

The below portion of my code caused recursive call on onEditorExit method. If I remove setData call, then no recursion occur.
What can be the workaround?

```
myGrid.addEditorExitHandler(new EditorExitHandler() {
    public void onEditorExit(EditorExitEvent event) {
        GWT.log("Hello");
        myGrid.setData(new ListGridRecord());
    }
});
```

Now check the console output -

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7krY.jpg)

Comment: What is the error message your receive?

Comment: Please check the attached screenshot.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, from user's perspective?

Comment: Probably that setData is launching an EditorExit event.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because each time you call `setData()` the editor will fire an `editorExit` event in an infinite loop (not recursively). By the way, calling `setData()` in the way you are doing will replace all your records in the `ListGrid` with one new empty record. This seems like a disconcerting user experience.

It looks like you want to create and start editing a new record when you tab out of the last one. In order to do that in a `ListGrid`, you use:

`grid.setListEndEditAction(RowEndEditAction.NEXT);`

That's all you need to do in order to get it working.